# Why is extended partition option is grayed out in GParted?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu, gparted

I'm trying to dual boot Lubuntu with macOS Sierra.

I boot using a USB flash drive, select "Try without installing", and when I launch GParted, see about 50GB unallocated space.

However, GParted extended partition option is grayed out.

I'm not a Linux admin by any means, not even close, so not sure what's going on here. 
See screenshot [image: here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a GPT disk. There are no extended partitions on GPT.
You can create almost unlimited number of primary partitions.

So create as many primary partitions as you need.

Comment: I'd like to create an exFAT partition for sharing data between Mac and Lubuntu but that option is disabled as well.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Create a NTFS partition.

Comment: `gparted` doesn't support exfat. You can format a partition to `exfat` in CLI. You can easily find a solution at AU.

Comment: Well, the partitioning worked, but exfat failed miserably. I've opened [another question](https://askubuntu.com/q/944531/641405) for that, will accept your answer for this one.

Comment: @MichaelBay There are no free macOS drivers that support NTFS.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Really? So you're saying you can't use any store bought external USB HDD? FYI, they're all NTFS.