# Lubuntu exFAT: Timed out waiting for device

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, lubuntu, exfat

I'm dual booting macOS and Lubuntu. I created a `/data` partition for sharing data between the two OS, and formatted it to exFAT as follows (NTFS is not an option because there is no free driver for it for macOS):

1. `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`
2. Using `Disks` utility and custom file system `exfat`, format. This finished with an error but subsequent `fsck` passed.
3. Reboot.

Now I get the following error at startup which eventually drops me in the maintenance mode.

```
Mounted /home.
Started File System Check on ...
Mounted /boot/efi.
Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2\...\x2...device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /data.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

The device name looks funny to me because the file separators are like Windows and there is a bunch of `x2` junk. I've since reformatted the partition in ext4 and then ntfs, and also commented it out from `/etc/fstab`, but the dang error just wouldn't go away.

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the above issue:

- `sudo apt-get install exfat-utils`. Reboot.
- Find out the partition identifier with `sudo fdisk -l`.
- Unmount the partition, where `/dev/sdXn` is the output from `fdisk` corresponding to `/data`.

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sdXn
  ```
- Format the partition to `exfat`:

  ```
  sudo mkfs.exfat -n Data /dev/sdXn
  ```
- Run a file system check, like so:

  ```
  sudo fsck.exfat /dev/sdXn
  ```
- If good, make an entry in `/etc/fstab` so that the partition is auto-mounted on reboot. To do this, find the partition UUID, which is given by the command `blkid`. If a previous entry exists for `/data`, delete it (formatting changes UUID).

  ```
  UUID=xxx  /data   exfat     default,nofail     0     2
  ```

The `nofail` is to prevent a disk check from holding up system boot. Reboot.